# Python: Split data at a specific string

Tags: python

I have a file here that looks like this:

```
|  | 
|:---- |
| ALPHA: 1234 |
|PLACE: somewhere1|
|0.111224443|
|0.22211441| 
|0.2344654|
|...|
|ALPHA: 5678|
|PLACE: somewhere2|
|1.23424345|
|0.98345|
|...|
```

Now I want to split this every time `"ALPHA..."` occurs, so that I can work with the Dara individually

I'm new to Python and don't know how to this
Maybe so that I create several from the one column, each starting at each new `"ALPHA..."`?

Comment: try using regex and use the line `re.split(r'\s*ALPHA.+\s*', file.read())`

Comment: members of SO will give help in coding problems or difficulties, not giving a complete solution from the scratch for a problem. Try coding by yourself and show what you've done! @sorae_

Comment: learn more about the split function in python

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but in general, to split a string in a particular place you would use `string.split(delimiter)`, therefore in your case `string.split("ALPHA")`. The result will be a list where "ALPHA" is not part of the output anymore.